# hacking jquery accordion in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-accordion

I am writing a nested menu with jquery's accordion.
There are up to 2 levels of nesting.
each header has to respond to two events:

1. if you click on the left-side half of the area, you select the item
2. if you click on the right-side half of the area, you open/close the item and the children are shown/hidden

those two events are mutually exclusive, and each has its own event handler.

the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>
    <a href="#">
       <span>some text</span>
       <span>more text</span>
    </a>
    <div class="lightning-rod"></div>
  </h3>
  <div>
     <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>
...
</div>
```

the div with class `.lightning-rod` is styled such that it covers the left-half of the element. A handler is bound to the "click" events and it handles the selection. If the user clicks on the right-side, the accordion will catch the click and do the toggling of the children.

This works in chrome, but IE9 is giving me problems.
In IE9:

- if I click on the right side, jquery handles the toggling and the toggling handler gets called.
- if I click on the left side, my `lightning-rod` div catches the click and calls the selection handler.
- **if I click on the text in the spans inside the a element, which is behind the `.lightning-rod` div, neither of my handlers gets called, and jquery toggles the children**.

Is there anything I can do for the `.lightning-rod` div to take precedence over the a element and catch the click as it does in chrome?

thanks

Comment: How did you style it and did you verify the Position of .lightning-rod with the development-tools?

Comment: @Grumbler85 yes. the lightning-rod div is positioned exactly as expected in IE9 and in the expected order (after the <a></a>). The CSS is position:absolute, height:100%, width: 50%, top:0px, left:0px

Comment: @Grumbler85 nice idea, but no cigar... it behaves the same as before.